# input focus issue with html/css on iphone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I have problem with my html/css code on iphone.
Visit this link  http://my-services-demo.botic-denis.com/ 
and click on search icon  in top bar.
After that You will see search bar.

Problem is starting when I click on search input box.

After that it seems like some element make body wider and I can scroll from left to right. Which shouldn't happen.

I can not find the issue causing this.

I have validate html and css.

Also I have another form on the bottom of the page. It is contact form and input fields are not making any problems on focus.

Comment: There is apparently a zoom issue on iOS when you click an input box the browser zooms in on that box, only way to fix is have the font size of the input box 16px or greater.

Comment: Thank You a lot Thomas, I have changed font size to 16px and this has finally resolved the issue. Would You like to publish your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accurate?

Comment: Thanks, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently a zoom issue on iOS when you click an input box the browser zooms in on that box, only way to fix is have the font size of the input box 16px or greater.

```
font-size: 16px;
```

Hope this helps.